# Django Template syntax error (Invalid block Tag)

Tags: html, django

I want to open my booking form page in my website but I got this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /form.html/
 Invalid block tag on line 61: 'end', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or 
 load this tag?
```

Here is my Code:

```
     {% if messages %}
     {% for message in messages %}
      <h2 style="color: green">{{message}}</h2>
      {% end for %} //the line I got the error
     {% end if %}
```

Comment: It is `{% endfor %}` without the spaces (you write `{% end for %}`, notice the space between `end` and `for`), similarly `{% endif %}`

Comment: oh yeah thanks I got it

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a space between the end and the keyword.

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    <h2 style="color: green">{{message}}</h2>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```